# what's kind of bike hooks should I buy for this wall mount?

Tags: mount

I moved in a new house and in the garage there is already a wall mount with parallel grooves, please see the first attached picture.

I know I can buy some certain hooks for this kind of wall that I can mount a bike on, because I saw it when I visited the house earlier(see the 2nd attached picture). However when I visited home depot or lowes I couldn't find something suiting this purpose - can anyone help me identify what kind of hooks I should buy that I can hook in this wall mount and hang my bike on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That is a slat wall system. If you can find a makers mark it will help to narrow down the options.

Comment: ask the real estate agent that sold the house to contact the seller and ask for the hooks to be returned

Comment: thanks to both. I supposed owner liked to keep the hooks maybe he had slat walls in their new house too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a configurable wall hanging design made by a company to work only with **their** proprietary hooks and brackets. I question why the seller took the hooks with them and not the board; one is worthless without the other.

Look for this brand, I think it's what you have:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I bought the proslat hooks as suggested and they just worked!